# Detect when the token is being bought / sold on an exchange (or swap-exchange like pankcake swap)?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, erc20

Is it possible to detect through an `ERC-20` token in `Solidity` if the token is being `sold` or `bought` from an exchange or a `swap-token-exchange` like `pancakeswap` ?

Is there a method for this in `Solidity` ? I want to have this `buy/sell` action trigger some other methods in the `token` contract...

Regular `wallet-to-wallet` transactions between users should not be picked up as `buy/sell`

Answer (score 0):

Just listen to the `Transfer` event and filter the address of the exchanges.

Comment: Huh, that's a solution... but how would it be possible to know which addresses/wallets are from the exchanges ? Is there a list / API for this that is offered by exchanges, for example : `binance.com` ?

Comment: eh idk, i guess you need to do it manually.

Comment: I see... so it would be possible then to have a function on the token contract, to add `exchange addresses` manually to be stored in variables, to detect with `transfer` if it came from an exchange or not ?